# How to set up a VPN effecting only one or few applications?

Tags: google-chrome, vpn, dropbox

I am currently in China (and this is why I cannot just Google this question). And I am struggling with the ISPs here since they practically blocked everything from the US, including Google, Facebook, Dropbox, Github, etc.

I can use a few VPNs here but they are all very slow (100KB/s). I even tried building a VPN myself by renting a server in California. But it doesn't really help. This is why I prefer to run just a few applications through the VPN (namely Chrome browser and Dropbox). I like to know how to accomplish this on OS X. Thanks.

Comment: You're talking about circumventing chinese law, its the government blocking you not the ISPs. As such, I dont believe its allowed here.

Comment: Using a VPN or using a proxy is pretty much your only solution.  As explained already, your ISP isn't blocking this content per say, your government requires this content to be blocked for your ISP to operate.

Comment: So much ignorance here... Chinese laws have clear exemptions for foreigners. It's also rather racist to say it's *their* government just because he has an Asian looking profile photo, despite saying he's from NYC.